# Unable to add fields to Redis index schema. Error: Cannot add more fields

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster, redisearch

I have an index created on Redis using FT.CREATE command. Now I want to add few more fields to the index. But I am getting the error below.

```
Cannot add more fields. Declare index with wide fields to allow adding unlimited fields
```

I have used the `FT.ALTER <index name> add <field name> TEXT` command.

Any help in understanding why I am not allowed to create attributes even though there is a limit of 1024 attribute limit on a schema is appreciated.

Comment: How many text fields do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to add up to a total of more than 32 fields, add to the index creation the option `MAXTEXTFIELDS`. See [FT.ALTER documentation](https://redis.io/commands/ft.alter/)